# convert microseconds into a human readable time

Tags: python, time

I need to convert a time difference (diff) between two actions into a human readable time.

How can I do this with python?
I tried something like

```
    diff = 49503757
    datetime.time(0,0,0,diff)
```

but the diff value was too long, the datetime expects a value of microseconds in between 0 and 999999 and my diff in this example was 49503757.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> str(timedelta(microseconds=49503757))
'0:00:49.503757'
```

Comment: it was microseconds .. so instead of 572 days I have 49 seconds. But thanks timedelta(microseconds=...) works fine

Comment: Yeap, sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: Hello there, this was of great help. But i want to strip off them after decimals in seconds. How to?